# How to resolve a react-hook-form from the client and server in Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, zod, shadcnui

I am using a react-hook-form use zod as a resolver. It has a `action` attribute to points to a function (`RegisterAccount`) that runs on the server and parses the form values and returns a `Promise<ZodError>`.

```js
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof registerFormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(registerFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        // ...
    }
})
```

```js
<form action={RegisterAccount}>
    // ...
</form>
```

Normally I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to do something like `onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}` but when I add that, RegisterAccount does not get called at all.

I'm also trying to use the `ZodError` that is returned from the server and somehow injecting that `ZodError` into the form. But I have no idea how to start on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write a client action that validates the data then calls the server action

```js
async function function action(formData: FormData) {
  const isValid = await form.trigger()

  if (!isValid) return 

  await RegisterAccount(formData)

  form.reset()
}


return <form action={action}>
    // ...
</form>
```

Note: some of react-hook-form (like isSubmiting, isSubmited, etc...) won't work with this approach

See this issue: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/10391

Or you can remove the action prop and call the server action directly within onSubmit callback